# Visual Studio Code Does Not Suggest Python Object Attributes

Tags: python, autocomplete, visual-studio-code, code-complete

I use VS Code v1.25.1 with the Python extension added. Although it suggests me the attributes and methods of libraries and classes, i.e. I type `from sklearn.` it makes suggestions like `ensemble, exception` etc., when I generate a numpy array `x_data = np.linspace(0.0, 10.0, 1000000)` and on the next line say I would like to use a method or an attribute such as `argmax` it does not show me the suggestion list after typing `x_data.`.

In Jupyter Notebook I used to press `tab` after typing `x_data.` to see the list. I wonder if there is any shortcut to achieve the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have [IntelliSense](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/intellisense) installed, it should work automatically as you type. Or you might try `Ctrl + Space`. It also depends on your configuration (see the link).